# External script in angularjs requiring parameters from serverside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, razor, angularjs-directive, filestack

I am trying to integrate filestack webpicker in my webpage. The requirment is to use angularjs.

I can add script tag direct in my cshtml file. But i want to have all the scripting part in angularjs.

```
<div class="js_file File__block" data-ng-controller="fileController">
<script src="//static.filestackapi.com/filestack- js/1.x.x/filestack.min.js">
</script>
 <script>
var options = {
        accept: "@Model.FileTypes",
        maxFiles: "@Model.NumberOfFilesAllowed",
        maxSize:"@Model.MaximumSizeAllowed",
        onUploadDone: showFileData

    }
const client = filestack.init('@Model.ApiKey');
client.picker(options).open();//Should only be 
called when use clicks the button

// Call back function
function showFileData (result) {
const file = result.filesUploaded[0];
..................
}

 </script>
```

And here is the angularjs

```
 angularApp.controller('fileController', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

$http.script = "//static.filestackapi.com/filestack-js/1.x.x/filestack.min.js";

const client = $scope.filestack.init("Api");

}]);
```

Can I send optional variables from cshtml by creating a javaobject and sending it to angularjs.

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Looks like something you would want to configure in an angular service

Comment: Will it be ok to have script tag in cshtml and all other intialization in angularjs controller

Comment: Depends how you include that cshtml. If it is used as a templateUrl the script tag will be sanitized